# Sending mail via SMTP through Rackspace from Laravel

Tags: laravel, rackspace

I'm trying to setup my laravel config to send through Rackspace but I keep getting a 501 response "invalid argument".  If I set laravel's mail config to send through gmail, it sends just fine, but when I set it up with the rackspace credentials, I keep getting 501, invalid argument. The error doesn't indicate which argument is invalid. Here is my config:

```
'driver' => 'smtp',
'host' => 'secure.emailsrvr.com',
'port' => 465,
'from' => array('address' => 'MYADDRESS', 'name' => 'MYNAME'),
'encryption' => 'ssl',
'username' => 'MYUSERNAME',
'password' => 'MYPASSWORD',
'pretend' => 'FALSE'
```

Am I missing something obvious in this config? Where is this 501 coming from, and why does gmail work fine?

Answer (score 1):

if your development environment is local,

```
pretend =  true
```